# Jquery: function doesn't allow to be appended

Tags: jquery, twitter

I'm trying to insert the [jquery function tweetable](http://theodin.co.uk/blog/javascript/tweetable-jquery-plugin.html) into a specific place in my HTML. The documentation says something like this:

```
$('#twitter').tweetable({username: 'username'});
```

The problem is that the tweetable HTML is placed *before* anything else inside the #twitter ID. In my case I want it at the end, so I tried this:

```
$('#twitter').append( tweetable({username: 'username'}) );
```

But Firebug says that `tweetable is not defined`. How should I call tweetable so that it can append to the #twitter ID?

**EDIT:**
A part of the source of tweetable that is probably interesting for solving this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.tweetable = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            limit: 5,
            username: 'twitter',
            time: true,
            replies: false
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function (options) {
            ...
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the plugin, try replacing this line:

```
$(act).prepend('<ul class="tweetList">');
```

...with this:

```
$(act).append('<ul class="tweetList">');
```

By the way, there are some things in the plugin that make me wonder about the quality of it.

Take the above code for example. Here `act` is already a jQuery object, so there's no need to wrap it again. You should be able to do `act.append('<ul...`.

It then proceeds to re-select the above element that was just created using `$('.tweetList')` instead of caching a reference to it. This is done in a loop inside the callback to the `getJSON` request. Terribly inefficient.

---

**EDIT:** Here's a version that allows an extra option called `position` which will accept `"append"` or `"prepend"` to be set.

It also caches the list. Other improvements could be made, but this is a little better anyway.

```
$('#twitter').tweetable({username: 'username', position: 'append'});
```

plugin:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.tweetable = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            limit: 5,
            username: 'philipbeel',
            time: false,
            replies: false,
            position: 'append'
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function (options) {
            var act = $(this);
            var $tweetList;
            var api = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=";
            var count = "&count=";
            $.getJSON(api + defaults.username + count + defaults.limit + "&callback=?", act, function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        $tweetList = $('<ul class="tweetList">')[defaults.position.toLowerCase() + 'To'](act);
                    }
                    if (defaults.replies === false) {
                        if (item.in_reply_to_status_id === null) {
                            $tweetList.append('<li class="tweet_content_' + i + '"><span class="tweet_link_' + i + '">' + item.text.replace(/#(.*?)(\s|$)/g, '<span class="hash">#$1 </span>').replace(/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig, '<a href="$&">$&</a> ').replace(/@(.*?)(\s|\(|\)|$)/g, '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1">@$1 </a>$2'));
                            if (defaults.time == true) {
                                $('.tweet_content_' + i).append('<small> ' + item.created_at.substr(0, 20) + '</small>');
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $tweetList.append('<li class="tweet_content_' + i + '"><span class="tweet_link_' + i + '">' + item.text.replace(/#(.*?)(\s|$)/g, '<span class="hash">#$1 </span>').replace(/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig, '<a href="$&">$&</a> ').replace(/@(.*?)(\s|\(|\)|$)/g, '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1">@$1 </a>$2'));
                        if (defaults.time == true) {
                            $('.tweet_content_' + i).append('<small> ' + item.created_at.substr(0, 20) + '</small>');
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixes it. It is a hack, but I already modified the code anyway (to make html output nicer and to give nicer created_at strings). It is indeed not that efficient, but much it has less code than all other plugins I found, which just had an overdose of functionality..

Comment: You're welcome. :o) I posted a version with some improvement. Specifically, with an additional option for "append" or "prepend" so it doesn't have to be hardwired. The list is also cached. Anyway, glad you got things figured out.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a new element, calling tweetable on that, and appending it to your current element?

```
var temp = $('<div></div>');
temp.tweetable({username:'username'});
$('#twitter').append(temp.html());
```

I haven't tested this, let me know if it doesn't work.  I am guessing it could be combined into one line:

```
$('#twitter').append( $('<div></div>').tweetable({username:'username'}).html() );
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working, if I remove the `.html()` part. The only trouble is that it adds yet another HTML element.. Then I get `div#twitter div ul#tweet_list` (the last one from tweetable). Any idea's on how to skip that?

Comment: @Lode what's the impact of having the extra tag?

Comment: @Lode The first part I posted was done so that you would get the contents of the created div without the div element.  Didn't that work?

Comment: @Fosco: `temp.html()` is an empty string.. If I just use `temp` it works, but _with_ the div wrapped around it.